# How to mix multiple builders on same package?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have an issue to mix several builders on single package.

In fact, I created build.yaml that contains the sources for file generation (JS builder), but when I need to test my web app (i.e. using build_web_compilers), it works only if I remove build.yaml file.

How to use both builders (JS builder + Web builder) without deleting/recreating build.yaml file ?

build.yaml

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      js_wrapping_generator|js_wrapping:
        enabled: true
    sources:
    - 'lib/src/*.dart'
    - 'example/*.dart'

builders:
  js_wrapping:
    target: "js_wrapping_generator"
    import: "package:js_wrapping_generator/builder.dart"
    builder_factories: ["jsWrapping"]
    build_extensions: {".dart": [".g.dart"]}
    auto_apply: dependents
    build_to: source
```

Versions

- Dart VM version: 2.0.0-dev.67.0
- build_runner: ^0.9.1
- build_test: ^0.10.2
- build_web_compilers: ^0.4.0
- source_gen: ^0.8.3
- test: ^1.2.0

Comment: There shouldn't be anything to do. Can you please add the content of the `build.yaml` file you are using?

Comment: build.yaml file added

Comment: I replaced `sources` by `generator_for`inside the builder and it works.